# How to convert a phylogeny to a dendrogram in R

Tags: r, phylogenetics, phylogeny

I want to convert my phylogeny into a dendrogram so I can use it with dendextend in R to produce a tanglegram. I have made some progress but I keep encountering errors, see below:

```
library(ape)
library(dendextend)

Tree <- rtree(10, rooted=F)

Tree <- read.tree(file="clipboard", text=NULL) 
# test <- as.dendrogram(Tree) 
## Error in ape::as.hclust.phylo(object) : the tree is not ultrametric

Tree.ultra <- chronos(Tree)  
# test <- as.dendrogram(Tree.ultra) 
## Error in ape::as.hclust.phylo(object) : the tree is not rooted

Tree.ultra$root.edge <- 0
# test <- as.dendrogram(Tree.ultra) 
## Error in ape::as.hclust.phylo(object) : the tree is not binary
```

This [thread](https://www.biostars.org/p/4576/) seems to be the closest to answering my issues but the workflow is different and Im not sure how to address this binary issue. I have tried using as.hclust, as.hclust.phylo and hclust.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1081936). Something that lets us test your code (and ours) and make sure our answers would work for you. A simple version of the tree you are using, for example, or even a way to generate random data that are similar to what you're working with.

Comment: Its not really clear to me (and maybe it is just me) what you mean? A dendrogram and a phylogeny are synonyms. Unless theres some suble difference I'm not aware of, so I'll let others enlighten me if thats the case.

Comment: Ive added a small example which incurs the same errors. @JoeHealey. Depends whom you ask about dendrogram vs phylogeny. Many say they are synonyms but classically a dendrogram is seen as a simple graphical representation of hierarchy vs phylogeny which is based on more sound and substantial, evidence and data.

Comment: If dendrogram is the same as cladogram than it contains just a tree topology, phylogeny is more general term, it frequently contains branch lengths corresponding to mutation rate * time. See this [post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-cladogram-and-phylogenetic-tree).

Comment: I was googling and it seems that [dendrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram) is a term used for visualisation of hierarchical clustering, which could be analogous to NJ-tree, but then it is not just a topology. If you mean cladogram, can you use this word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching high and low I have found an answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445684/how-to-convert-a-tree-to-a-dendrogram-in-r)

Workflow goes like:

```
library(DECIPHER)
dend1 <- ReadDendrogram(file="clipboard") 

# Alternatively to load from existing environment 
Tree$node.label <- NULL # Need to remove node labels
dend1 <- ReadDendrogram(textConnection(write.tree(Tree)))
```

This object can then be used in the dendextend package and tanglegram function.

Comment: Does that give different results than the chronos function?

Comment: Contrary to what you say, you can read a character string from within R by passing a [`textConnection`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/textConnection) to `ReadDendrogram`.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph I was not aware of that. Im only a novice to be honest. Ill change my answer above to include this.

Comment: Hi @KonradRudolph I have been trying the text connect as so:` dend1 <- ReadDendrogram(textConnection(Tree))` but I get an error. `Error in textConnection(Tree) : invalid 'text' argument`

Comment: @AudileF Did you read the documentation? What’s `Tree`? A representation of the dendrogram in text format?

Comment: @AudileF not sure if you've figured it out already but what you should have done is `dend1 <- ReadDendrogram(textConnection(write.tree(Tree)))`

Comment: I hadn't actually @august thanks a mill I'll include it above now.

Answer (score 2):

For your example to work you should replace the `rtree` function with the `rcoal` function, see example below.

```
library(ape)  
library(dendextend)   
Tree <- rtree(10, rooted=F)
is.ultrametric(Tree) 
[1] FALSE 
is.binary.tree(Tree) 
[1] TRUE

Tree_rcoal <- rcoal(10, rooted=F) 
is.ultrametric(Tree_rcoal) 
[1] TRUE
is.binary.tree(Tree_rcoal) 
[1] TRUE

Tree_rcoal2 <- rcoal(10, rooted=F)

tanglegram(Tree_rcoal, Tree_rcoal2)
```

To make use of a file in newick format, you can try to convert with the `chronos` function.

```
s <- "owls(((Strix_aluco:4.2,Asio_otus:4.2):3.1,Athene_noctua:7.3):6.3,Tyto_alba:13.5);"
cat(s, file = "ex.tre", sep = "\n")
tree.owls <- read.tree("ex.tre")
is.ultrametric(tree.owls)
[1] FALSE
dendrogram <- chronos(tree.owls)

Setting initial dates...
Fitting in progress... get a first set of estimates
         Penalised log-lik = -24.04992 
Optimising rates... dates... -24.04992 
Optimising rates... dates... -24.04908 

Done.
is.ultrametric(dendrogram)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi b.nota. Thats all well and good but I have an actual newick file I need convert to a dendrogram. rtree was to give an example for troubleshooting. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But you didn't mention any newick file in your original post. Check [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445684/how-to-convert-a-tree-to-a-dendrogram-in-r this post from years ago, I think the chronos function might be helpful in your case.